# Swift Struct Property with Generic Enum

Tags: swift, enums

I am currently creating settings page. I am trying to dynamically assign an Enum into my struct property. 
What I want to achieve is that whenever Settings struct is being called, it will automatically append all respective settings together. Below are the enums

```
protocol BaseSettings {}

enum SettingsCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case sales = "Sales"
    case payment = "Payment"
}

struct SettingsSection {
    var settingsNameArray: [BaseSettings]
    var settingsCategoryName: SettingsCategory

    init(settingsCategory: SettingsCategory) {
        self.settingsCategoryName = settingsCategory

        switch settingsCategory {
        case .sales:
            self.settingsNameArray = SalesSettings.allCases
        case .payment:
            self.settingsNameArray = PaymentSettings.allCases
        }
    }
}

struct Settings {
    var sections = [SettingsSection]()

    init() {
        for eachSettingCategory in SettingsCategory.allCases {
            self.sections.append(SettingsSection(settingsCategory: eachSettingCategory))
        }
    }
}

enum SalesSettings: String, BaseSettings, CaseIterable {
    case testSettings = "Test Sales Settings"
}

enum PaymentSettings: String, BaseSettings, CaseIterable {
    case testSettings = "Test Payment Settings"
}
```

Above codes are working fine. The settings are grouped by section. However, when I want to populate the String raw value of each enum case, I am facing a problem. I couldn't get the rawValue because of the Protocol BaseSettings is not an enum

```
 let settingsDataSource = SettingsConstant.Settings()
 let settingsName = settingsDataSource.sections[indexPath.section].settingsNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(settingsName)"
```

Instead of displaying the rawValue of each enum case, the tableView is displaying each of the enum case.

How can I fix this data structure? Can anyone guide me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify in the protocol declaration that you need a raw value!

```
protocol BaseSettings {
    var rawValue: String { get }
}
```

Enums such as `SalesSettings` would automatically conform to this new requirement because it is exactly the same as `RawRepresentable.rawValue` when `RawValue` is `String`.

Comment: Wow Sir! yes it works! And if let's say the enum SalesSettings has a getter property, how can i access that? Hopefully you can help me this one :)

Comment: @alvinWB You first need to make sure that the instance of `BaseSettings` is actually an instance of `SalesSettings`: `if let ss = settingsName as? SalesSettings { /* access "ss.yourProperty" here*// }` but without more information, my advice will probably not be the best. I suggest you post a new question, with more information.

Comment: Thanks sir for the help! Previously XCode won't let me cast it to SalesSettings. It seems because I put the SalesSettings inside an enum. When I remove the SalesSettings enum from the Wrapper enum, I can cast it already :). Very much thanks!